# Replicating PHP's bin2hex() function

Tags: apex, encryption

I am beginning an integration project where the password needs to be encrypted and they have given the php example of using bin2hex(md5('password')). I am trying to replicate php's bin2hex() function, but I am not quite sure how.

```
md5('password');
```

produces: 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99

```
bin2hex(md5('password');
```

produces: 3566346463633362356161373635643631643833323764656238383263663939

In apex I am able to get 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99 by:

```
Blob hash = Crypto.generateDigest('MD5', Blob.valueOf('password'));
String stringValue = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(hash);
```

Do I have to "manually" (create my own function) convert each character separately? ie. 5 = 35, f = 66, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bin2hex` in Apex:

```
String s = '5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99';
System.debug(EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Blob.valueOf(s)));
```

This will print `3566346463633362356161373635643631643833323764656238383263663939` to the log.

Salesforce provides a safe way to store passwords out of the box - take a look at [Storing Sensitive Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/wiki/secure_coding_storing_secrets)

Comment: I swear I tried that 15 times last night and was never able to product that result. I think I need more sleep. Thanks